# Force login using "appc login" with out asking for email and password to enter

Tags: appcelerator-cli, appcelerator

I am trying to configure my Titanium code in CI machine. To run build everyday. Currently I am facing problem with "appc login" command. 
Where this command need inputs from user (Email, password, Org and Env)

is there any way I can pass those inputs with command or any force way to login with waiting for user inputs.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run below command to do that.

**Format**:

```
   $ appc login --username <email> --password <password> --org-id <orgid> --env <envname>
```

**Example:**

```
$ appc login --username test@gmail.com --password test@123 --org-id 10128 --env production
```